# How to craft POST request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, post

I'm trying to submit a POST request from localhost:81 to a running web application on my localhost:80. This is the [code](https://pastebin.com/eU6YA5cf) on the web app.

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST[ 'btnSign' ] ) ) {
    // Get input
    $message = trim( $_POST[ 'mtxMessage' ] );
    $name    = trim( $_POST[ 'txtName' ] );
 //full code is above on link
```

You may recognize it from Damn Vulnerable web Application. My POST request is made through an HTML page. Javascript code of [HTML page](https://pastebin.com/Z5NDf44R):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:81/vulnerabilities/xss_s/?', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            // do something to response
            console.log(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send('textName=person&mtxMessage=password&btnSign=Sign+Guestbook');
    </script>
```

In order to craft my request parameters I based myself on the source code and requests intercepted with the browser done on dvwa website. My question here is: Am I doing the POST request right? Does it matches what PHP file is expecting to parse?

Comment: I'd do it differently, but I guess it is correct... the best way to know is to actually try it out... have you run the code?

Comment: @Zeke Yes! It returns 302 status code and doesn't update database. As you can [see](https://imgur.com/a/CQtgt)

Comment: @Zeke how would you do it?

Comment: Regardless of how I'd do it, your code works. `302 Found` is the status code, therefore this article might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Comment: I see in the screenshots that your code worked perfectly, the data was encoded and sent, so I think it's safe to say you just have to resolve what's causing the `302` status code.

Comment: In other words, check your `../../login.php` file, because that's the `Location` header on your console.